# Getting Directions on Maps (Windows phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, bing-maps, directions

I'm trying to get directions between two points, either by using the MapControl or the Maps application on the phone, i found this to launch the maps application [here](http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/12/07/wp7-tip-pseudo-map-launcher/)

works perfectly, but is there a url to get the directions between two points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this [Calculate a Route - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx)

Comment: I have used it, it doesnt give me the exact route (sometimes it gets off the road) thats why i want to use the maps application.

Comment: Does the BingMapsDirectionTask fit your use case?